# How to customize error message on Siri intent response of type `failureRequiringAppLaunch`

Tags: ios, ios13, siri, sirishortcuts

I'm adding a Siri intent to my app for it to be used within the Shortcuts app. The user needs to be logged in in order to use the intent. When he is not, I send a failure completion with the code `.failureRequiringAppLaunch`.

For classic errors, *ie* not needing the app to be launched, I added a `String` property to customize the error message for the user.

[image: Intent configuration]

Unfortunately, when I call the completion with the `.failureRequiringAppLaunch` code, the error message is not displayed, and the message "An unknown error occurred." is displayed to the user:

[image: Error popup]

Here is my code:

```
let intentResponse = AllMeetingsIntentResponse(code: .failureRequiringAppLaunch, userActivity: nil)
intentResponse.failureReason = "You must log in to use this function."
return intentResponse
```

So if someone is able to tell me how I can customize the "app launch" alert, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your error message by doing the following:

```
let response = AllMeetingsIntentResponse.failure(failureReason: "Fail because Bla bla bla")
completion(response)
```

I hope it helped you

Comment: Unfortunately not... What you propose is just to customize the message for a classic failure. What I need is to configure the message for the "requiring app launch" failure. The one intended to tell the user why they need to launch the app (in my case, to log in)

Comment: But the classic failure as the button to open the app and continue in the app.
You can always open a new issue in apple. I have been working on SiriKit for the last few days and I have been experiencing many limitations :(

Comment: I totally agree about limitations, however with a simple and classic failure I only have the `OK` button available...

Comment: have you found and answer to that?

Comment: Did u found the answer to that issue? @Zaphod

Comment: Unfortunately still no answer to that...